# Taylor Series, Newtons Method and Newton Raphson

Tags: taylor-expansion, newton-raphson

I am currently learning about different optimization methods. That is, I am interested in finding the maxima/minima of functions. The last method I have studied is Newton Raphson.

I understand Newton Raphson. As far as I understand it, Newtons method is simply the first order case of the Newton Raphson method. Is this correct?

Now, how do both of these methods relate to the concept of Taylor Series? It might be a trivial question but I am a bit confused, because these concepts seem to overlap a bit.

Comment: The methods have utterly different purposes. Taylor series are used to approximate a function, Newton's method and its refinements to find roots. A relation might however be that Taylor gives a good start value.

Comment: I just watched this lecture by Gilbert Strang: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0xlKuFqCuI. In the very beginning, he derives Netwons Method for finding $f(x)$. To me it seems like it is just the first order Taylor series, this confuses me a bit. But maybe I just need to read more.

Comment: Thanks. So from my understanding, the Taylor Series of a function provides the starting point to how one can approximate a function at a given point. One can use the first order series to try to find the minimum iteratively (Gradient Descent), or use the second order series to find the minimum iteratively (Newton Raphson (NR)). However, I am a bit confused by the third link you provided. It says that NR utilizes $-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$. However, I thought one uses $-\frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no distinction between Newton's method and the Newton-Raphson method, they are the same thing.

As for how Newton's method relates to power series. In the optimization context, Newton's method (iteratively) optimizes the best quadratic approximation to a function $f$ at a point $x_0$, which is given by truncating its power series at the second order term,

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^n}{n!}\approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2.$$

Taking the derivative of the quadratic approximation and setting it equal to zero gives us,

$$x=x_0-\frac{f'(x_0)}{f''(x_0)}.$$

Thus optimizing the best quadratic approximation to $f$ gives rise to the familiar root finding algorithm on $f'$, where each iteration in the root finding algorithm is equivalent to reforming the best quadratic approximation at each step of the optimization algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the Newton Method applied to optimization is just the "original" root finding algorithm applied to the derivative, correct?

Comment: @shenflow essentially yes.